# Como inserir a média da coluna em todos os valores NA

Tags: r

Olá.

Como inserir a média em todos os valores NA. Tenho um código que leio o arquivo, verifico se tem na e não tem, mas quando transformo em número, aparecem vários NA e se eu remover, os dados ficam bem reduzidos de 4000 para cerca de 600:

```
df<-read.csv("autores.csv", header=T, stringsAsFactors=F, sep=";")  

table(is.na(df))  #não há NA

df_numero<-lapply(df[-1], as.numeric)  

#recria o dataframe pois lapply retorna lista  
df1<-data.frame(df_numero)  

table(is.na(df))  #há NA
```

Comment: Isso deve ser porque os dados precisam de ser limpos, provavelmente há carateres estranhos tais como vírgulas (`1,234.00`)  ou coisas assim. Veja primeiro como é que os valores que desaparecem de `df` estão e só depois aplique `as.numeric`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segue código para substituir os `NA` pela média da coluna onde eles se encontram:

```
for(i in 1:nrow(df)){
  for(j in 1:ncol(df)){
    if(is.na(df[i,j])){
      df[i,j] <- mean(df[,j], na.rm = T)
    } 
  }
}
```